# Problems with K-means clustering in R

Tags: r, algorithm, cluster-analysis, k-means

When I try to do K-means clustering on standard iris data

```
library('tidyverse')
iris_Cluster <- kmeans(iris[, 3:4], 2, nstart = 10)
iris$cluster <- as.factor(iris_Cluster$cluster)
p_iris <- ggplot(iris, aes(x = Petal.Length, y = Petal.Width, color=cluster)) + geom_point()
print(p_iris)
```

[image]

I get one point belongs to wrong cluster. What is the problem? Is this weakness of K-means clustering algorithm? How to get appropriate result? What are good algorithms for partitional clustering?

Comment: You need to scale so that the x axis is the same as the y axis. Then you'll get a different visual fix on the supposedly stray point.

Comment: If you want to ask about other clustering methods, you should do so at [stats.se] or [datascience.se]. That's not a specific programming question that's a good fit for Stack Overflow. This question is not unique to R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point that belongs to the "wrong" cluster is point 99.
It has Petal.Length = 3 and Petal.Width = 1.1.  You can get the 
centers of your clusters from

```
iris_Cluster$centers
  Petal.Length Petal.Width
1     4.925253   1.6818182
2     1.492157   0.2627451
```

You can see the distance from point 99 to the cluster centers using

```
as.matrix(dist(rbind(iris_Cluster$centers, iris[99,3:4])))
          1        2       99
1  0.000000 3.714824 2.011246
2  3.714824 0.000000 1.724699
99 2.011246 1.724699 0.000000
```

Point 99 *is* closer to the cluster center at (1.49, 0.26).
The problem is that k-means chooses the cluster center that is 
closest to a point, not the center that makes sense based on things 
like the cluster of nearby points. As suggested by @Anony-Mousse , 
DBSCAN may be more to your liking. The DB part stands for Density Based 
and it creates clusters in which the points can be connected through 
regions of high density.   Another option is single link hierarchical 
clustering that tends to put points that are near each other in the 
same cluster.

Mimicking your code but using `hclust`:

```
library(ggplot2)
iris_HC <- hclust(dist(iris[,3:4]), method="single")
iris_Cluster <- cutree(iris_HC, 2)
iris$cluster <- as.factor(iris_Cluster)

p_iris <- ggplot(iris, aes(x=Petal.Length, y=Petal.Width, color=cluster)) + geom_point()
print(p_iris)
```

[image: Cluster data]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, by the sum-of-squares objective, this point belongs to the red cluster.

Consider, e.g., DBSCAN.